# Simulating constant, deceptive, reactive and random jammers in Castalia

Tags: omnet++

I am trying to simulate different kinds of jamming attack in a routing protocol.

For example, to simulate constant jamming, I have configured the `jammer state` to **`TX`** and `**TxOutputPower**` to `*-5dbm* (others have -25dBm)`. So that it constantly transmits.

I am using *BypassMac* for the jamming scenario. I have put jammer so close to a node so that effect could be seen. But there is basically no change in that node, the TXed and RXed packets are almost the same for both general and jamming configuration.

Can anyone please tell me how to achieve 100% jamming attack?

Comment: It would help if you could attach your omnetpp.ini file so that others can reproduce your scenario (if you are not using custom code)

Comment: I have used ThroughputTest app for 2 nodes and a customized throughput app for jammer node.
`SN.node[0].xCoor = 0
SN.node[0].yCoor = 0
SN.node[1].xCoor = 15
SN.node[1].yCoor = 0
SN.node[2].xCoor = 15.5
SN.node[2].yCoor = 0`
#Jammer test application
`SN.node[2].ApplicationName = "JammerApp"
SN.node[2].Application.packet_rate = 100
SN.node[2].Application.constantDataPayload = 2000
SN.node[2].Application.startupDelay = 0
SN.node[2].Communication.Routing.maxNetFrameSize = 2500
SN.node[2].Communication.MAC.maxMACFrameSize = 2500
SN.node[2].Communication.Radio.maxPhyFrameSize = 2500`

Comment: It would be better to add these details by editing your question. It's hard to read in a comment. Make it as easy for us to help you.

Comment: You indicated that you have also made your own application module. If you do not provide any details on that, we don't have enough info to help you. Read these suggestions from the help centre on how to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: thanks for the link.. I needed that, I was struggling to post the codes. 
I just changed a little bit of ThroughputTest app and made that new jammer app to ensure it TXs most of the time (0.01s) and sends the packet to the broadcast network address. Setting `constantDataPayload = 2000` should make the packet larger, isn't it?

Comment: Good, I am expecting to see a complete question in the description then, with everything we need to replicate your simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details on your simulation, it's difficult to draw conclusions.

One thing that might be the culprit is that your jammer is not in TX mode most of the time. For example, if you are sending short packets infrequently enough, it will be improbable to collide with packets from other nodes.